# Looking for a dc 2pin connector with latch

Tags: dc, connector, bnc, panel-mounting

I'm looking for a pair of connectors with following features.

- about 10V rating (no high voltage)
- 5A
- 2 pins
- latch which will prevent from accidential unplug
- panel mount

I want to mount the socket on alluminium scheet.

I dig through internet, but the only connectors which I found (which comply with above requirements) is BNC. Can you help me and propose something else?

I'm not sure if i can use BNC as about 4Amps connectors, it's kinda unproffesional.

Comment: The XLR type connectors used on microphones might be suitable. I would avoid the standard 3-pole version as that is in very common use.

Answer (score 1):

Aluminium sheet, or aluminium pcb. Not exactly sure how you want to mount it. But maybe these through hole molex connectors [image]

Part Number: 26-01-3127

Mini-Fit Jr. Header, Dual Row, Right-Angle, with Snap-in Plastic Peg PCB Lock, 2 Circuits, PA Polyamide Nylon 6/6 94V-0, 0.38µm Gold (Au) Plating

Comment: Big fan of this connector family.  +1
They are also available in [panel mount](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0039012021_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml)

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is to find a suitable connector family that has more pins and the wire up multiple pins in parallel through the connector. This lowers the current rating needed per pin whilst opening up the available selection of connectors.

So for a 4-pin connector use two pins for PWR and two for GND with a current rating of 2.5A per pin. A 6-pin connector would offer three pins each for PWR and GND and get by with a rating of less than 2A per pin.

Using this technique can sometimes be an advantage when it comes to building the mating cable. Instead of one larger conductor in the cable you can run multiple smaller conductors which can end up with a more flexible cable and not having to bridge multiple connector pins to a single conductor in the connector backshell.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a hobby application, try what the Chinese call "aviation connectors". Two pin are rated at 5A.

They're circular connectors that have a nut that holds them together. Very inexpensive and fairly sturdy.